# Bootstrap 3 - Use "Refresh" Glyphicon to Reset Text Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, input-field

How do I reset an input field by clicking on a "refresh" glyphicon in Bootstrap 3?

Existing HTML:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="person@company.com" /><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.fa.fa-refresh').click(function(){
 $(this).prev().val('');
});
```

Comment: I put that in my <head> and it's not doing anything. :/

Comment: put it after the body. right before the `</body>`. the DOM doesnt exists in the head